# How do I run shell with custom Error handler?

Tags: cakephp

I have custom AppError class which starts with

App::import('Core', 'Error');

When I try to run any shell script I run into "Fatal error: cannot redeclare class ErrorHandler in ...\cake\libs\error". It seems the ErrorHandler for console is loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply extend the ErrorHandler class if it is already loaded?

```
<?php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
}   
?>
```